# What kind of employment protections do freelancers and subcontractors have?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, employment

Many companies hire independent freelancers and subcontractors for their specific expertise. However, they're not really "employees" of the companies that hire them. What kind of rights/protections do such freelancers have with regards to their employment? Or do they have no special rights, and are completely subject to whatever contact/agreement they sign with the company?

For example, if such individuals are harassed by other employees of the company, are they protected by EEOC laws? Or the inventions created by the freelancer e.g. [Labor Code Section 2870](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=LAB&division=3.&title=&part=&chapter=2.&article=3.5.)?

Comment: A full answer is complicated. The short answer is not many protections.

Comment: "What kind of rights/protections do such freelancers have with regards to their employment?" Since they're not employees, they don't have employment.